# SQL Query with multiple JOINS on multiple tables

Tags: mysql

I have created this query to match data against multiple tables but i feel that it has got a little complicated.

I need to select from the following tables:

- leads
- instructors_options
- instructor_calendar

using the following relationships:

```
leads.sequence = instructors_options.instructor_seq
leads.sequence = instructor_calendar.instructor_seq
```

and the following filters MUST match:

- lead.lead_type = 'Instructor'
- instructors_options.option_name = 'pupil_cap' AND instructors_options.value > 0
- instructors_options.option_name = 'car_type' AND instructors_options.value = 'variable'
- instructors_options.option_name = 'areas_covered' AND instructors_options.value = 'variable'
- instructor_calendar.pupil_name = 'AVAILABLE' AND instructor_calendar.date >= 'variable' AND instructor_calendar.date <= 'variable'
- instructors_options.option_name = 'diary_updates' AND instructors_options.value = '1'

  ```
    SELECT    i.sequence as instructor_seq, 
                  ic.date AS date, 
                  ic.start_time AS start_time, 
                  ic.end_time AS end_time
          FROM 
              leads i 

          LEFT JOIN 
              instructors_options io 
          ON 
              i.sequence = io.instructor_seq AND 
              (io.option_name = 'pupil_cap' AND io.value > '0') 

          RIGHT JOIN 
              instructors_options io2 
          ON 
              i.sequence = io2.instructor_seq AND 
              io2.option_name = 'car_type' AND io2.value = '".$bookingData["car_type"]."' 

          RIGHT JOIN 
              instructors_options io3 
          ON 
              i.sequence = io3.instructor_seq AND 
              io3.option_name = 'areas_covered' AND (io3.value LIKE '".substr($postcode, 0, 1)."' OR io3.value LIKE '".substr($postcode, 0, 2)."' OR io3.value LIKE '".substr($postcode, 0, 3)."' OR io3.value LIKE '".substr($postcode, 0, 4)."')

          RIGHT JOIN 
              instructors_options io4 
          ON 
              i.sequence = io4.instructor_seq AND 
              io4.option_name = 'diary_updates' AND io4.value = '1' 

          RIGHT JOIN 
              instructor_calendar ic 
          ON 
              i.sequence = ic.instructor_seq AND 
              ic.pupil_name = 'AVAILABLE' AND 
              ic.date >= '".ChangeDateFormat($date, 'Y-m-d')."' AND 
              ic.date <= '".date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date. ' + 7 days'))."' 
          WHERE 
              i.lead_type = 'Instructor' 
          GROUP BY date 
          ORDER BY date ASC, start_time ASC
  ```

Can someone please help me update my query to ensure I have done it correctly

Thank you!

Comment: Is this a MySQL question, or a SQLServer question? These are two VERY different products, and you have them both tagged.  Why?

Comment: Sorry - my mistake, must have accidentally clicked sql-server

Comment: The first thing I notice is that you are looking for "MUST" matches, but have LEFT and RIGHT joins. Are you sure you don't want INNER JOIN? And you either have an extra join (io4) or you missed that in the requirements list :)

Comment: Can you explain the cardinality between the tables? I think it's `Leads(1)-<(0)Instructors_options` and `Leads(1)-<(0) w/ instructor calendar`... but do calendars relate to options at all?  or is this a true cross join?

Comment: @JacobH - missed that one off - see update :)

Comment: @xQbert instructor_calendar links to leads with leads.sequence = instructor_calendar.instructor_sequence and instructors_options links with leads using leads.sequence = instructors_options.instructor_seq

Comment: @charlie and that answers none of my questions.  I don't know the 1-M relationships and I don't know if there's any relation at all bet ween calendar and options.  So I'm taking the answer as no relation and that you have a 1:M between Leads and the other two tables.  1-M is a question on how many records in leads relate to records in IO and IC.  so 1 lead record relates to zero to many options and 1 lead record has zero to many calendar records?

Comment: im not sure what you mean by 1-M relationships? and NO there is not a relationship between calendar and options which is why i didnt put it in my last comment :)

Comment: @xQbert 1-M - yes this is correct, there is a 1-M for leads-instructors_options and leads-instructor_calendar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for certain calendar entries. So select from that table.

One of the conditions is that the related instructor sequence has all of four certain options. So aggregate the options per instructor sequence and keep those who match all criteria. Use an `IN` clause to get the calendar entries for these instructor sequences.

```
select 
  instructor_seq,
  date, 
  start_time, 
  end_time
from instructor_calendar 
where pupil_name = 'AVAILABLE' 
and date >= '2017-01-01' 
and date <= '2017-05-31'
and instructor_seq in
(
  select instructor_seq
  from instructors_options
  group by instructor_seq
  having sum(option_name = 'pupil_cap'     and value > 0)   > 0
     and sum(option_name = 'car_type'      and value = 123) > 0
     and sum(option_name = 'areas_covered' and value = 456) > 0
     and sum(option_name = 'diary_updates' and value = 1)   > 0
);
```

The `HAVING` clause makes use of MySQL's `true = 1`, `false = 0` by the way.

Comment: ok, i can give this a test. another thought just now, currently this is searching between the selected date and the selected date + 7 days. if no results are returned, i run exactly the same query again but change the date filters. Can i run this all in one query so if no results are returned, it will remove the second date<= clause?

Comment: In standard SQL you would simply select both weeks, then rank your records by week with `ROW_NUMBER` and keep the best ranked week. MySQL lacks this function. You'd usually emulate this with variables in MySQL.

Comment: ok, scrap my last comment. i'll keep rerunning the query if no results are found. I need to loop through the dates initially then the time for each date. is the best way to run another query inside a loop?